# Updating link on page via REST api

Tags: rest-api

I have a page that I need to periodically update the file location for a link to point at a new file.  Trying to do this via a Python script using `requests`.

I've got authentication set up via 'Application Passwords' plugin, and I'm able to download a json from the api for the page in question.  I have a pre-built string that contains the new file location, ready to go.  I extract the page content, specifically the 'rendered' version, as a string.  I do a quick `replace()` on that string between two known tags (`<h4>`) and then reload the modified 'rendered' page content back into the json, and upload it back to the endpoint, again using `requests()`.

When it's all said and done, I'm getting no errors from the script, a status code of 200... but nothing changes on the page.

Furthermore, I'm finding the following in the error log:

> [21-Aug-2019 00:12:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/example/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php on line 778

Not exactly sure what that means, but I'm assuming it's not good.

```
import base64, json, requests

user = 'admin'
pythonapp = 'QUDM PYFn xfyK 9Hhe Ayf2 hk6k'
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2'

data_string = user + ':' + pythonapp

token = base64.b64encode(data_string.encode())

headers = {'Authorization':'Basic ' + token.decode('utf8')}

newsletterURL = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/lorem-ipsum.pdf'
oldH4 = '<h4><a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/NCWGC-2019-8.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)">Click here to download the newsletter!!!</a></h4>'
newH4 = '<h4><a href="' + newsletterURL + '" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)">Click here to download the newsletter!!!</a></h4>'

#  Download the current Newsletter page
r = requests.get(url + '/pages/6', headers=headers)

tmp = r.json()
```

Pretty sure the code up to this point works as intended/expected; obviously it's been somewhat modified to be a stand-alone example vs. part of the larger script.

```
oldPageContent = tmp['content']['rendered']
# print(oldPageContent.partition('</h4>')[0])

newPageContent = oldPageContent.replace(oldH4, newH4)
# print(newPageContent.partition('</h4>')[0])

tmp['content']['rendered'] = newPageContent
# print(tmp['content']['rendered'].partition('</h4>')[0])

r = requests.post(url + '/pages/6', headers=headers, json=tmp)

# print(json.loads(r.content.decode('utf8'))['content']['rendered'].partition('</h4>')
```

Here I'm attempting to replace the specific URL inside the body content, reassemble things, and upload the whole thing back to the

```
"content": {
    "rendered": "\n<h4><a href=\"http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/NCWGC-2019-8.pdf\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer noopener\" aria-label=\" (opens in a new tab)\">Click here to download the newsletter!!!</a></h4>\n\n\n\n<p>Submissions for the newsletter are always welcome. Space is somewhat limited so keep \u2019em short and sweet!",
    "protected": false
}
```

This is an example of the specific field that I'm trying to extract from the content of the page, update, and upload.

Kinda thinking maybe I should be using `json.dumps/loads` to get at `['content']['rendered']` rather than just `r.json()`?  Though when I print out the resulting strings, they sure *look* like right...

Any ideas/suggestions for updating a page via the REST api?  Or am I going about this completely wrong?

**Update:**

*After the excellent help from @SallyCJ, this is the final form of what I ended up with, in case it helps anyone else down the road:*

---

```
import base64, json, re, requests

user = 'admin'
pythonapp = 'QUDM PYFn xfyK 9Hhe Ayf2 hk6k'
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2'

data_string = user + ':' + pythonapp

token = base64.b64encode(data_string.encode())

headers = {'Authorization':'Basic ' + token.decode('utf8')}

#  Temporary URL for the sake of testing
newsletterURL = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/lorem-ipsum.pdf'

#  Download the current Newsletter page
r = requests.get(url + '/pages/6', headers=headers)

#  Extract the actual page content from all the rest of the API data
data = r.json()
content = data['content']['rendered']

#  Find the URL for the download in 'content', and replace it with the new URL
regex = r"(http(s)?)://(www.)?(example.com\/wp-content/uploads\/).+(pdf)"
newContent = re.sub(regex, newsletterURL,content)

#  Create a new data payload using the updated 'content'
data = {"content": newContent}

#  Upload it back to the site
r = requests.post(url + '/pages/6', headers=headers, json=data)
```

Comment: Perhaps double-checking the relevant endpoint/route [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) would help. But I'm guessing you're not sending the proper parameters when updating the page..

Comment: Unfortunately the examples in that reference are a little... sparse... on details, at least for updating the page.

That said, I think you're probably correct;  I did some more poking around, and I can do other operations via the api without any difficulty, just not updating that page.  Not sure *what* I'm not doing right, though...

Comment: Well, if you can show your code.. or the request parameters, then maybe I can help?

Comment: @SallyCJ put the code and commentary in the original post.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is with your `POST` request, where the `content` property should be a plain string** and not an object. **You should also send just the data that you want to change.**

When updating a Page (i.e. a post of the type `page`), you should provide a JSON-encoded *or* URL-encoded string containing one or more of the properties/parameters as listed [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#update-a-page).

Examples using [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) from the command line prompt:

- URL-encoded (`Content-Type` header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

  ```
  curl -d "title=New%20Title!&content=New%20Content%3F" -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/9 --user "admin:QUDM PYFn xfyK 9Hhe Ayf2 hk6k"
  ```
- JSON-encoded

  ```
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"title\":\"New Title!\",\"content\":\"New Content?\"}" -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/9 --user "admin:QUDM PYFn xfyK 9Hhe Ayf2 hk6k"
  ```

So in your code:

- This line:

  ```
  tmp['content']['rendered'] = newPageContent
  ```
- should be:

  ```
  tmp = { 'content': newPageContent }
  ```

  but you can of course add other properties that you want to change; e.g. `title` and `status`.

And (despite that I'm *not* a Python expert), you can use the example below as a reference when creating/retrieving/updating/deleting a Page:

```
import base64, json, requests

user = 'admin'
pythonapp = 'QUDM PYFn xfyK 9Hhe Ayf2 hk6k'
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2'

data_string = user + ':' + pythonapp
token = base64.b64encode( data_string.encode() )
headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode( 'utf8' ) }

# Create a Page.
data = { 'title': 'Testing from Python' }
r = requests.post( url + '/pages/', headers=headers, json=data )
data = r.json()
page_id = str( data['id'] )
print 'Page created. ID: ' + page_id

# Retrieve the Page.
r = requests.get( url + '/pages/' + page_id, headers=headers )
data = r.json()
title = data['title']['rendered']
print 'Page #' + page_id + ' retrieved. The title is: ' + title

# Update the Page.
data = { 'content': 'New content here' }
r = requests.post( url + '/pages/' + page_id, headers=headers, json=data )
data = r.json()
content = data['content']['rendered']
print 'Page #' + page_id + ' updated. Content set to: ' + content

# Delete the Page.
r = requests.delete( url + '/pages/' + page_id, headers=headers )
data = r.json()
print 'Page #' + page_id + ' moved to the Trash. (Well, it should be...)'
print 'The Page "status" is ' + data['status']
```

Comment: I had wondered about sending the whole payload back vs. just the specific field I'm concerned with.  Good to know!

One other question on sending the content back... when I retrieve it, it is in a structured/nested format, with "content" returning sub-levels of "rendered" and "protected".  Do I need to just update to "content", or to "content": "rendered": "<h4>Foo</h4>"?

Comment: As I said, you just need to update to "content" :) - that structured thing indicates an object (e.g. `"content":{"rendered":"Foo bar"}`) which WordPress returns in the response when retrieving a Page/Post/etc. But when updating the resource, you'd use just `"content":"New content here"`. I.e. Send "content" as a string.

Comment: Finally got time to play with this tonight.  Being able to extract the "content" as a string (rather than trying to manipulate nested dictionaries), update the specific URL using `re.sub` and then just upload that particular piece (rather than the whole payload) turns out to be *way* simpler than what I was trying to do before!  Thanks!!!